# Lazy resolution of dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have .net classes
I am using unity as IOC for resolving our dependencies.
It tries to load all the dependencies at the beginning.
Is there a way (setting) in Unity which allows to load a dependency at runtime?

Answer (score 10):

There's even better solution - native support for Lazy<T> and IEnumerable<Lazy<T>> in the Unity 2.0. Check it out [here](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2010/05/lazy-and-ienumerable-support-comes-to.html).

Comment: Don't forget this line `unityContainer.AddNewExtension<LazySupportExtension>();` and the reference `PM> Install-Package Unity.Extensions.Lazy `

Answer (score 1):

Unity should be lazily constructing instances, I believe. Do you mean that it is loading the assemblies containing the other dependencies? If that's the case, you might want to take a look at [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) - it's designed specifically for modular applications.

Answer (score 1):

I have blogged some code [here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/08/lazy-loading-of-dependencies-in-unity.html) to allow passing 'lazy' dependencies into your classes. It allows you to replace:

```
class MyClass(IDependency dependency)
```

with

```
class MyClass(ILazy<IDependency> lazyDependency)
```

This gives you the option of delaying the actual creation of the dependency until you need to use it. Call `lazyDependency.Resolve()` when you need it.

Here's the implementation of ILazy:

```
public interface ILazy<T>
{
    T Resolve();
    T Resolve(string namedInstance);
}

public class Lazy<T> : ILazy<T>
{
    IUnityContainer container;

    public Lazy(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public T Resolve()
    {
        return container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public T Resolve(string namedInstance)
    {
        return container.Resolve<T>(namedInstance);
    }
}
```

you will need to register it in your container to be able to use it:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILazy<>),typeof(Lazy<>));
```

Answer (score 0):

in .net core use "Lazy Resolution" : remove both constructor injection of both classes and instantiate other class only when need to use it by injecting the .net IServiceProvider namespace.
[image]

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Service2>().Hi();
```

Use **constructor injection default** and **only** use Lazy Resolution when you have to.